# SQL access optimisation

Tags: sqlite

So, I have 2 tables:

```
items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, imgurl text, defindex int, name text),
prices (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, defindex int, quality int, effect int, currency text, price real)
```

And if I need to look up item's name, price and effect name, I execute 2 queries:

```
SELECT currency, price from prices where defindex = :def and effect = :eff and quality = :qua
SELECT name, imgurl from items where defindex = :def
```

I want to replace it with 1 query, but problem is that sometimes there is item without price, so defindex 202 exists in items, but not in prices, so

```
select prices.currency, prices.price, items.name, items.imgurl from items,prices where items.defindex = :def and prices.defindex = :def and prices.quality = :qua and prices.effect = :eff
```

Will not work.
 How do I make this into one query without making it slower?

Comment: Why do you think that two queries would be noticeably slower? Joining two tables is likely to take more effort than two simple table lookups.

Comment: I am just in progress of optimising my website that takes too much to load, and I thought that database requests take time to be passed from python to actual db.

Comment: Do you think this, or have you measured this?

Comment: I didn't measure, but SQL is optimised, but Python is slow, so many requests instead of one are probably time-wasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an outer join
something like this

```
Select i.name, i.imgurl, p.currency, p.price 
from items
left join prices on i.defindex = p.defindex
Where i.defindex = :def and effect = :eff and quality = :qua
```

note, this will be all items and the price if there's one for that effect and quality.

Revised version

```
Select i.name, i.imgurl, p.currency, p.price 
from items
left join prices p on i.defindex = p.defindex and p.effect =:eff and p.quality = :qua 
Where i.defindex = :def
```

When no matching price effect and quality would be null so the where clause on my original attempt chopped them out. My apologies.

Comment: `select name from items where defindex = 5719;` returns item name, while `Select items.name, items.imgurl, prices.currency, prices.price 
from items
left join prices on items.defindex = prices.defindex
Where items.defindex = 5719 and effect = 0 and quality = 6;` return absolutely nothing.

Comment: ah hold on, I know what it is.